# NestJS E2E tests with Jest. Injected service returns undefined (only tests)

Tags: dependency-injection, jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing, class-validator

I have a problem with the end-to-end testing of my users module. I want to validate if there is a "companyCode" when a user makes a GET request in /users and sends this code in the query params. This validator searches the database if this company code exists, if it does not exist it returns an error. The problem is that in the test this validation doesn't happen, because "companiesService" returns undefined (only in the test), what's missing?

Possible Solution: something related to **useContainer(class-validator)**.

Thanks.

---

**users.e2e-spec.ts**

```
describe('UsersController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let repository: Repository<User>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UsersModule, AuthModule, TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormConfig)],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_GUARD,
          useClass: AuthGuard,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
    useContainer(app.select(UsersModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });

    repository = module.get('UserRepository');
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  describe('/users (GET)', () => {
    it('should return users if requesting user sent "companyCode" in the request body', async (done) => {
      return request(app.getHttpServer())
        .get('/users')
        .auth('admin', 'admin')
        .query({ companyCode: '2322661870558778503' }) // should return 200 because companyCode exists but is returning 400
        .expect(200)
        .then((res) => {
          expect(res.body.users).toHaveLength(1);
          done();
        })
        .catch((err) => done(err));
    });
  });
});
```

---

**users.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService, UserExistsRule],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      User,
      Person,
      Type,
      Profile,
      UserProfile,
      Company,
    ]),
    CompaniesModule,
  ],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

---

**read-users.dto.ts**

```
export class ReadUsersDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(1)
  @MaxLength(255)
  public name?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumberString()
  @Type(() => String)
  @Validate(CompanyExistsRule)
  public companyCode?: string;
}
```

---

**companies.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  providers: [CompaniesService, CompanyExistsRule],
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Company, Person])],
  exports: [CompaniesService],
})
export class CompaniesModule {}
```

---

**companies.decorator.ts**

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'CompanyExists', async: true })
@Injectable()
export class CompanyExistsRule implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(private companiesService: CompaniesService) {}

  async validate(code: string) {
    try {
      console.log('companiesService', this.companiesService); // returns undefined on test
      await this.companiesService.findOneByCode(code);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  defaultMessage() {
    return `companyCode doesn't exist`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I imported useContainer from typeorm instead of the class-validator hahahahha.

```
// incorrectly imported
import { useContainer } from 'typeorm';  

// correctly imported
import { useContainer } from 'class-validator';
```